# Where is Lubuntu Next 17.10 LXQt?

Tags: lubuntu, 17.10, lxqt

Ubuntu 17.10 is already released. But where is the promised release of Lubuntu 17.10 with LXQt? the latest ISO is the daily image from 14 October.

Comment: @EliahKagan from their web site: What’s improved since 17.04? -We now ship with Linux Kernel 4.13.-General bug fix release as we prepare to switch to LXQt....  so what that means? no LXqt release in October?

Comment: @EliahKagan but it is not clear, what means "bug fixes as we prepate to switch to lxqt"? they are fixing bugs in lxde because they are prepare to lxqt?

Comment: Apparently, "General bug fix release as we prepare to switch to LXQt" is not specific to 17.10 at all, but [was also in the "What's improved" lists](http://lubuntu.net/blogs/lubuntu) for the previous two releases! So you're right--that page doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Softpedia announced on 10/21 that LXQt 0.12.0 is now available, and said on 10/23 that the ISO for the official release contains 0.11.0.  Guess it means install and update, but there are some heavy-duty changes involved!

Comment: thanks for info!! is the any links to download? i can't find any(

Answer (score 1):

From:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu-next/daily-live/pending/

"You can download the Lubuntu Next images here. Please note that these images are VERY experimental and should NOT for ANY REASON be used in production. We mean it!"

They are dated: 2017-10-14 17:30 or thereabouts... about 5 days earlier than the "standard" Ubuntus.

Comment: but it is unfortunately still unstable version... any info when will be the stable?

Answer (score 0):

17.10 uses LXDE, not LXQT.

[image]

The same [with 18.04](https://lubuntu.net/lubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-released/).

Now the "promissed" LXQT Lubuntu is 18.10 (Cosmic), yet to be released at the time of my post, but available as daily (unstable~buggy) build: [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/HEADER.html).

Some people have tested it and posted videos [on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=lubuntu%2018.10&page=&utm_source=opensearch).

---

(I personally use LXQT on top of Kubuntu 18.04 and I think will stay with it even after 18.10 is released because I want Dolphin and Kwin anyway.)